# Trying to Build my First Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I came across the video tutorial here.

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/03/rtvs-preview.html

Right around minute 24:15 the instructor starts talking about the shiny app that he built.  He has it pre-built, and simply runs it, so it's basically impossible for me to figure out how he actually went from nothing to a real working app.  I watched a few tutorials on YouTube, and they were helpful to get me up to speed a little, but still can't get this working.  As best as I can tell, these are (kind of) the steps, but again, I stil can't get this working.

RStudio > File > New File > Shiny Web App.  Then name the app and crate a directory.

Now, I have a template that looks like this.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Based on the video, I created a template (with some basic R code).  It looks like this.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(plyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("recalc", "New points"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Order Locations", leafletOutput("map",width="80%",height="400px")),
      tabPanel("Markers", verbatimTextOutput("markers"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  airports <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat", header = FALSE)
  colnames(airports) <- c("ID", "name", "city", "country", "IATA_FAA", "ICAO", "lat", "lon", "altitude", "timezone", "DST")
  countries <- sort(unlist(lapply(unique(airports$country), as.character)))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This doesn't do anything at all.  Ugh.

I believe the 'ui' is a function that calls arguments form the 'server'.  Is that right?  Am I close, or way off base?  How can I get this working?  It seems VERY useful.  I'm trying to learn the nuts and bolts of this stuff so I can do it myself.  Thank you!

Comment: It's probably better to follow the official Shiny tutorial here http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Comment: I just found that same video, right before I posted my question.  I'll try to go through the whole thing today or tomorrow.  Thanks.